# ui-view in index rendering index page

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've looked all over for this and maybe I'm just not searching for the right question.

I have two ui-view elements in my index.html page. The first ui-view renders index.html including the head tag and all the js files instead of the template and I can't figure out why.

in my index.html page I have two ui-views.

```
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div ui-view="banner"></div>
    <div ui-view="master"></div>
  </div>
```

I have ui-router routes set up like this.

```
$stateProvider
        .state('index',
        {
            url: '/',
            views: {
                'master': {
                    templateUrl: 'landing.html',
                    controller: 'mainController'
                },
                'banner': {
                    templateUrl: 'banner.html',
                    controller: 'mainController'
                },

            }
        });
```

This is what the result looks like

[[image: code[1]]

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any help you can give will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Wow! I hate it when that happens!! I spent hours trying to figure out what was going on. Finally figured out that I had misspelled the name of the file "banner" to bannen. Thanks for looking if you did.